# Is there a way to send meta data when opening a WebSocket?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I'm looking for a way to send a unique identifier to the server when opening a WebSocket.

I could implement this by sending an handshake message after being connected, but it would be very nice if that wasn't needed and instead I could just send and read the identifier via meta data, similar to header fields in http requests.

Is there a way to send meta data when opening a WebSocket?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The WebSocket connection is initiated via an `HTTP GET` request. So you can include meta-data in the `GET` headers, like you would for any other request. Alternatively, you can append some params in the query string of the ws endpoint: `ws://site.com/stream?param=foo`, and parse the data on the server-side (will be received as a GET request).

[See here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket#WebSocket_protocol_handshake)

Comment: ah, thats a smart idea! I'm using the WebSocketServer of [ws](https://github.com/einaros/ws) (node.js), and when opening a WebSocket client on an url like `ws://localhost:3000/?id=123456` (mind the slash after the port number), I can read the query parameters server side via `connection.upgradeReq.url`, which then contains `/?id=123456` in that case. Thanks!